# Application of Dynkin's formula

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^d, (W_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a $d$-dim. Brownian motion. I have the following processes
$$
Z_{t, x} = b(Z_{t, x})dt + \sigma(Z_{t, x})dW_t, \qquad Z_{0, x} = x \\
V_{t, v} = \nabla b(Z_{t,x})V_{t,v}dt + \nabla \sigma(Z_{t,x})V_{t,v}dW_t, \qquad V_{0, v} = v\\
U_{t, v, v'} = (\nabla b(Z_{t,x})U_{t, v, v'} +  \nabla^2b(Z_{t, x})[V_{t, v'}]V_{t,v})dt \\ + (\nabla \sigma(Z_{t,x})U_{t, v, v'} +  \nabla^2\sigma(Z_{t, x})[V_{t, v'}]V_{t,v})dW_t, \qquad U_{0, v, v'}=0,
$$
i.e. a stochastic process and its first and second variation process, formally derived by differentiating $Z_{t, x}$ in direction $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and then $v'\in\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $(P_t)_{t\geq0}$ denote the transition semigroup, i.e. $(P_tf)(x)=\mathbb{E}[f(Z_{t,x})]$. Can someone explain, why Dynkin's formula would lead to

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ (P_tf)(x) \int_0^t\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s, v, v'}, dW_s \rangle \right] = 0?
$$
To my knowledge, letting $\mathcal{A}$ denote the infinitesimal generator, Dynkin's formula reads
$$
(P_tf)(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(Z_{t,x})] = f(x) + \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t(\mathcal{A}f)(Z_{s,x})ds\right] \\
= f(x) + \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \langle b(Z_{s,x}), \nabla f(Z_{s,x}) \rangle +  \langle \sigma(Z_{s,x})\sigma^T(Z_{s,x}), \nabla^2 f(Z_{s,x}) \rangle_{\mathrm{F}} ds\right],
$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_F$ denotes the Frobenius scalar product. I don't see how that helps here...

Comment: My word the notation is complicated. Can you provide the PDF/textbook/paper/talk video  where you saw these expressions and reasoning? I am asking you just in hope that there's some intuition regarding $Z,V,U$ and so on, because at the moment they seem so arbitrary to me! I still think your problem is down to putting notation properly and doing the computation carefully, which I'm willing to do provided everything is a little clearer to me than at present.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon This is the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06972.pdf). The process $Z$ is defined on p. 5, $V$ and $U$ on p.28, the cited eqn. is on p.31 (starting with $\mathbb{E}[J_{3, x}]=~...$). I think the solution is easy, though, and as you said I was indeed not seeing the forest for the trees. $(P_tf)(x)$ is deterministic, so it factors out of the expectation, and then we're left with a sum over expectations of integrals w.r.t. to a brownian motion, which is zero? Does that make sense?

Comment: Let me have a look and get back. The paper you have attached seems a nice read, so I will go through all the material and make sure that you are correct. +1 to your question, for participating and otherwise putting in MathJax.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If my comment is correct, I'd still be wondering why the authors claim to use Dynkin's formula here...

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out that as well. I have an explanation for the whole $E[J_3(x)]$ simplification somewhat ready, but I feel that it is incomplete until I find out what Dynkin's formula has to do with it. No clue till now.

Comment: You are right , however, about the forest from the trees. Indeed, that term is zero because the $P_tf(x)$ slips out, and then the expectation of a stochastic integral is $0$. Don't know what this has to with Dynkin's formula then. I am not able to get out of the second line, though.

Comment: I have solved the entire expression, and I don't see Dynkin's formula used anywhere. To see a concrete use of Dynkin's fomula, we see page 32 for usage of Dynkin's formula on both $V_{t,v}$ and $U_t$, where clearly derivative terms and so on are seen. So I think there's a typo, since only the Ito formula $(29)$ (and the fact that the stochastic integral) gets used to simplify $E[J_3(x)]$ . Can you suggest what would be a good answer to this question, now that we have this observation?

Comment: I think your last comment together with the fact that $(P_tf)(x)$ can be drawn out and the expectation of the stochastic integral is $0$ can serve as an answer. I'm happy to accept that if you want to post that as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that. I will take my time, and in addition add a few more things I need to, so that this answer can be of help to others than just you. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Introduction to the paper

This answer focuses on the paper attached [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06972.pdf). The paper measures sample quality using diffusions. The main idea for this is the idea of Stein's discrepancy method, a powerful idea in probability theory which allows the upper bounding of usual probabilistic distances by an appropriate Stein discrepancy. The Stein discrepancy involves the use of Ito diffusions, and in order to ensure that the Stein operator is well behaved, one needs good bounds on the behaviour of the underlying semigroup of the Ito diffusion, which we call $P_t$. The Ito diffusion will be called $Z_{t,x}$, the initial point being $x$ and time being $t$. We have $P_t f(x) = \mathbb E[f(Z_{t,x})]$.

##### On the use of Dynkin's formula

The main reference for stochastic calculus of the paper is Avner Friedman, *Stochastic Differential Equations And Applications*. As per the paper , equation (7.10) of the text has the following statement :

> Dynkin's formula : Under suitable integrability conditions ,
> $$
> \mathbb Eu(\xi(t),t) - \mathbb Eu(\xi(0),0) = \mathbb E\int_0^\tau Lu(\xi(s),s)ds
> $$
> where $u(\psi(t),t)$ is a suitable function, $d\xi(t) = A(t)dt + B(t)dw(t)$ is an Ito diffusion and $L = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j} (B^TB)_{ij} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} + \sum_{i} A_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the associated semigroup operator of $\xi$.

It is clear, that the use of Dynkin's formula must involve differentiation of a certain kind, since $L$ involves the same.

For a clear use of Dynkin's formula, we witness page number $32$ of the paper, where we see that in both applications of Dynkin's formula, derivatives clearly appear on the functions $\sigma$ and $b$.

##### The story of $\mathbb E[J_3(x)]$

To compute $\mathbb E[J_3(x)]$, nowhere is Dynkin's formula used, unlike what the author says. Indeed, what is used is equation $(29)$ at the end of page number $30$.

$$
f(Z_{t,x}) = (P_tf)(x) + \int_0^t \langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}) ,\sigma(Z_{s,x}) dW_s\rangle
$$

which is derived by applying the Ito formula to $(s,x) \to P_{t-s}f(x)$, a $C^2$ function.

From there, we have :
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[J_3(x)] & = \frac{1}{t} \mathbb E\left[f(Z_{t,x}) \int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right]  \\ &= \frac{1}{t} \mathbb E\left[\left((P_tf)(x) + \int_0^t \langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}) ,\sigma(Z_{s,x}) dW_s\rangle\right) \int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right] \\ &= \frac 1t \mathbb E\left[P_tf(x)\int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right] \\ &+ \mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}) ,\sigma(Z_{s,x}) dW_s\rangle\int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right]
\end{align}

Of these, the first term vanishes since the $P_tf(x)$ comes outside the integral and we are left with the expectation of a stochastic integral, which is a martingale starting at $0$ hence has constant expectation equal to $0$. For the second term, we observe the form of Friedman's Ito theorem statement and how it was translated here, and obtain by expansion a result which I find bewildering but definitely true :
$$
\left\langle\Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}) ,\sigma(Z_{s,x}) dW_s \right\rangle= \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m [\Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x})]_i  \sigma(Z_{s,x})_{il} (dW_s)_l \\ = \sum_{l=1}^n (\Delta P_{t-s}f(Z_{s,x})\sigma(Z_{s,x}))_l (dW_s)_l =\left\langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}) \sigma(Z_{s,x}), dW_s   \right\rangle
$$

which is kind of saying that the $\sigma$ term can come from right to left side. I don't know why it was kept on the right in the first place, this could have even been a typo for all I know.

Anyway, now we come to :
$$
\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x})\sigma(Z_{s,x}), dW_s\rangle\int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right]
$$

and are in the "covariance of Ito-Integrals" territory. Indeed, by equation (7.1) of Friedman applied coordinatewise, we get :
$$
\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x})\sigma(Z_{s,x}), dW_s\rangle\int_0^t \left\langle \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'},dW_s\right\rangle\right]
 \\ = \mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \left\langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x})\sigma(Z_{s,x}), \sigma^{-1}(Z_{s,x})U_{s,v,v'}\right\rangle ds\right]$$

whence we can again use the same coordinatewise expansion logic we applied last time in the Ito integral form, for this expression to bring the $\sigma^{-1}$ over to the left of the $\sigma$ and cancel out, to get :
$$
\mathbb E\left[\int_0^t \left\langle \Delta (P_{t-s}f)(Z_{s,x}), U_{s,v,v'}\right\rangle ds \right]
$$

which is the final expression obtained by the authors of the paper as well.

##### Final thoughts

I feel that the paper skips many steps, and struggles to integrate its notation with that of the standard reference. However, the use of the Stein discrepancy in this particular instance is very nice, and I would suggest going through the paper without really looking at the details and just understanding the flow and what is happening in general, because it should not take too much effort for an expert to fill in details if and when required.

Comment: Congrats on your taxicab answer! :)

Comment: @LightYagami Apologies, I don't know what that means. Are you referring to the Ramanujan incident , where Hardy tells him he came in a taxi numbered 1729? I don't recall having written an answer based off that. This answer is correct, I think the downvote is scattered. I do, however, mildly regret reading that paper. It is very very poorly written. It is almost like they want to cover the intuition, and just want to brush the details under the carpet so kept the details very terse and poorly jointed.

Comment: Yes I was referring to [Taxicab numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20nth%20taxicab,%3D%2093%20%2B%20103.). I don't have to say anything related to this answer because I don't understand this, I am preparing for JEE.

Comment: @LightYagami Oh, it's my 1729th answer! On the exact day that I celebrate my fifth anniversary on Stack Exchange as well! It is extremely rare that I get downvoted, mostly scatter, so I'm a little unhappy at the end of the day, but well, that was nice! Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @LightYagami I hope you read the answer before doing so. I don't want this to look rigged , that's the point.But thank you! If you like, I'll run you basically through what's going on in the paper. Keeping in mind the JEE background, of course. Not today, I'm too sleepy. But on a good day, maybe tomorrow you can pop in [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi) to ask for it.

Comment: I don't even know what stochastic even means... can I understand that?

Comment: @LightYagami I will explain everything about this answer, considering your background. The simplest possible explanation will come. Of course, on another day that suits us.

Comment: Sure, I will ask tomorrow then!

Comment: @LightYagami I'm sure we are on the same time zone, so : good night!

Comment: @LightYagami Ready?

Comment: @LightYagami Actually, maybe another day. Probably a weekend, because I am not free unfortunately right now. If you are preparing for the JEE we will do this once you are a little free, I am sure your schedule will be up and down due to these factors. Please reply when you'd like to hear, I am sure you will like it.

Comment: yes, that is why I didn't ask today. I have my JEE MAINS day after tomorrow. So after that, sure!

Comment: @LightYagami Good luck for the same. Hope to see some good questions from there on the site, hopefully good quality well written questions.

Comment: I am done now with my exam. Now you can explain this answer whenever you get time... BTW I am also a great fan of THE MENTALIST..it is my favourite show!!!